# What word best describes a line of posts connected by a retractable belt?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was at a building that I've never been to before, and someone directed me to follow the *samtons* to the other side. I am hard-of-hearing, so I wasn't able to fully hear how they pronounced it, but I got a pretty good idea of what it sounded like. It was something like *samtons* or *hamptons*. They are usually placed on both sides to force people to walk in a narrow line, sort of like a one-way maze.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Stanchions.*

From https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanchion

> Stanchions are used for many different purposes, including crowd control and waiting lines. Many different places use stanchions, including banks, stores, hotels, museums, restaurants, concert venues, trade shows, and other events.[citation needed]

> Portable posts used to manage lines and queues.

> Fixed posts with decorative ropes, custom printed belts, or metal wires. Often available in single, double, and triple belt/wire configurations.

> Retractable belt stanchions, often with a slow retract belt mechanism for safety.

The last are the type you observed, common in airports.

Comment: Also commonly known as "retractable barriers" if you Google, but clearly this is the word the OP wanted.